# DB procedure triggered one minute

Tags: oracle, primefaces, jsf-2, websphere-portal

My JSF 2 app (with PrimeFaces 5.3) is running on Websphere Portal 7 and I'm having some problems with quite time consuming action on `p:commandButton`. Click on a button calls an EJB method on WAS that calls a DB procedure (extensive database work that roughly takes a few minutes). This procedure should make an entry in a DB table every time it's called (one entry per call). But I noticed that a db entry is made every minute until a procedure work is not finished. As an example, I clicked the button and there were three entries made in a db table (the first one immediately after click, then another one after one minute, then another one two minutes after the first one).

Could it be some portal server setting causing that behaviour? Is it a db feature? Maybe a JSF thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily check if the 2nd post is done by the browser or not. Check the network traffic from the browser. But better yet, make the request/response async by using websockets!

Comment: @Kukeltje I already wrote that another request is made after one minute. What I'd like to know is why is the second request sent and how to prevent that. And afaik WAS 7 (it's where Websphere portal 7 is running) doesn't support websockets.

Comment: Historically, the Websphere 'proxy' module, created a new request to the java-ee server after x time and not the browser. Hence my question. Easiest thing to do is to check the PrimeFaces javascript source that does the ajax calls and see what is in there. The source is open.

Comment: Oops, that was weblogic.... But the async part remains (long polling should work as a fallback in PrimeFaces)

Comment: @Kukeltje I changed my question. My mistake, I thought that there were multiple requests per click but there was just one. However, there's a problem with multiple db entries, although there should be just one entry per ejb method call (button click). Any idea where should I look for a solution?

Comment: No, sorry, debug... Set breakpoints...